# Algebraic identity I cannot solve

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, standard-deviation, means

$$  \sum_{i<j}\sum_{j=1}^N(y_i-y_j)^2=  N \sum_{j=1}^N(y_i-\bar{y})^2          $$
Where, $\bar{y}$ is the average.

This is what I did:
$$  \sum_{i<j}\sum_{j=1}^N(y_i-y_j)^2\\=\sum_{i<j}\sum_{j=1}^N((y_i-\bar{y})-(y_j-\bar{y}))^2 \\= \sum_{i<j}\sum_{j=1}^N(y_i-\bar{y})^2+\sum_{i<j}\sum_{j=1}^N(y_j-\bar{y})^2-2\sum_{i<j}\sum_{j=1}^N(y_i-\bar{y})(y_j-\bar{y}) $$

Now, the third term is zero as $(y_i-\bar{y})$ can be taken outside of the inner summation. I tried to simplify further but, it did not work out finally. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [I had done something similar a few months ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881206/math-formulas-on-clustering/881280#881280), but I would like to see if there is a cleaner way...

Comment: I see, my problem is equivalent to what you do, and then I guess it works out  :D

Answer (score 2):

$$  \sum_{i<j}\sum_{j=1}^N(y_i-y_j)^2=  N \sum_{j=1}^N(y_i-\bar{y})^2          $$
Where, $\bar{y}$ is the average.

This is what I think might work given a clue from @angryavian:
$$  \sum_{i<j}\sum_{j=1}^N(y_i-y_j)^2\\=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N((y_i-\bar{y})-(y_j-\bar{y}))^2 \\= \frac12\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N(y_i-\bar{y})^2+\frac12\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N(y_j-\bar{y})^2-\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N(y_i-\bar{y})(y_j-\bar{y})\\=\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N(y_i-\bar{y})^2\\=N \sum_{j=1}^N(y_i-\bar{y})^2    $$
Note, the third term from the expansion of the square is zero as $(y_i-\bar{y})$ can be taken outside of the inner summation. What say?
The second step follows from symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical identity regarding the variance. Let $Y,Z$ be two i.i.d. variables distributed uniformly over $y_1,\ldots,y_N$. The right-hand side of the identity is
$$ N^2 \mathbb{E}[(Y-\mathbb{E}Y)^2] = N^2 \mathbb{V}[Y]. $$
For the left-hand side of the identity, notice that if we replace the first sum by a sum over all pairs $i,j$ then we double the resulting value. Undoing this process, we deduce that the left-hand side is
$$ \frac{1}{2} N^2 \mathbb{E}[(Y-Z)^2]. $$
Therefore the identity is equivalent to
$$ \mathbb{E}[(Y-Z)^2] = 2\mathbb{V}[Y]. $$
To prove this, the trick is to replace $Y-Z$ with $(Y-\mathbb{E}Y)-(Z-\mathbb{E}Z)$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[(Y-Z)^2] &= \mathbb{E}[((Y-\mathbb{E}Y)-(Z-\mathbb{E}Z))^2] \\ &=
\mathbb{E}[(Y-\mathbb{E}Y)^2] + \mathbb{E}[(Z-\mathbb{E}Z)^2] - 2\mathbb{E}[(Y-\mathbb{E}Y)(Z-\mathbb{E}Z)] \\ &=
\mathbb{V}[Y] + \mathbb{V}[Z] - 2\mathbb{E}[Y-\mathbb{E}Y]\mathbb{E}[Z-\mathbb{E}Z] \\ &=
2\mathbb{V}[Y] - 2\cdot 0\cdot 0 \\ &= 2\mathbb{V}[Y].
\end{align*}
$$